# Como modificar um extrato diario para um extrato mensal?

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma tabela que não está nas formas normais de banco de dados, mas tem dados antigos que eu preciso obter.

Eu consegui fazer com que me apresentasse o extrato diário, mas agora preciso modificar para que gere o extrato mensal na seguinte query:

```
SELECT dia, mes, ano, credito, debito, format(saldo,2) as saldo
FROM (
    SELECT
        dia,
        mes,
        ano,
        credito,
        debito,
    @dc := dc AS tipo,
    @saldo := IF(@dc = 'C', @saldo + credito, @saldo - debito) AS saldo
    FROM lc_movimento, (SELECT @dc := 'C', @saldo := 0) as vars
    ORDER BY ano, mes, dia
) AS extrato
```

Este é o link da demo:

[Tabela no SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0b1f43/6)

Este é o resultado desejado.

```
    mês   ano     credito   debeito          saldo
    5     2014     2500     8722,6          -6222,6
    6     2014     0        12792,96        -19015,56
    7     2014     0        10884,82        -29900,38
    8     2014     0        10884,82        -40785,2
    9     2014     0        10022,68        -50807,88
    5     2015     650      7580,25         -57738,13
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui chegar ao resultado mas tive que criar um VIEW. Usei uma dica do @Maniero e deu tudo certo.

Me cheira uma gambiarra, mas funcionou.

Segue o *link* demo [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7090e/6).

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(data,'%d/%m/%Y') AS data,
    SUM(IF(tipo = 'D', valor, 0)) AS debito,
    SUM(IF(tipo = 'C', valor, 0)) AS credito,
    (SELECT SUM(IF(tipo = 'C', valor, -valor)) FROM vw_extrato AS L2
         WHERE DATE_FORMAT(vw_extrato.data,'%Y%m') >= DATE_FORMAT(L2.data,'%Y%m')
    ) AS saldo
FROM vw_extrato
GROUP BY MONTH(data), YEAR(data) ORDER BY data desc
```

Comment: A *view* não é necessária mas até facilita a leitura da consulta. Aceite sua resposta.